# Edit nested dictionary with limited information

Tags: python, dictionary

How can i change the 'space' of 'albert' if i dont know if he is a donkey or a zebra?

```
self.object_attr = {'donkey': {
                              'name': 'roger', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}{
                              'name': 'albert', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [1, 1]}
                    'zebra': {
                              'name': 'pain', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}{
                              'name': 'alesha', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [1, 1]}}

print self.object_attr
for species in data.values():
    for animal in species:
        if animal['name'] == 'albert':
            animal['space'] = [50, 50]

#output      this is what object_attr is
{'donkey': {'roger': {'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}, 'albert': {'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}}}


#the error occurs on the "if animal['name'] == 'albert':" line
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, it looks like your data is missing some punctuation.  I made best guesses as to what was missing.

```
data = {'donkey': [{ 'name': 'roger', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}, { 'name': 'albert', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [1, 1]}],
      'zebra':  [{ 'name': 'roger', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}, {'name': 'albert', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [1, 1]}]
}

for v in data.values():
    [item.update({'space':[50, 50]}) for item in v if item['name'] == 'albert']

print data
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'donkey': [{'name': 'roger', 'space': [0, 0], 'zone': 'forrest'},
        {'name': 'albert', 'space': [50, 50], 'zone': 'forrest'}],
 'zebra': [{'name': 'roger', 'space': [0, 0], 'zone': 'forrest'},
       {'name': 'albert', 'space': [50, 50], 'zone': 'forrest'}]}
```

Comment: Why not use `data.values()`, since you're not using `k`?

Comment: @zigg: Good point, I will update.  I started off with a different approach and was going to need k, but alas I do not.

Comment: Using list comprehensions for side effects is not very Pythonic

Comment: @gnibbler:  Agreed.  Now I am ashamed.

Comment: I sometimes think there should be `void()` function something like `void = lambda it: collections.deque(it, maxlen=0)`

Answer (score 3):

**edit:** Based on the output you provided, the following should work:

```
data = {'donkey': {'roger': {'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}, 
                   'albert': {'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}}}

for species in data.values():
    if 'albert' in species:
        species['albert']['space'] = [50, 50]
```

Original answer below:

---

Here is a pretty straightforward way to do this:

```
data = {'donkey': [{'name': 'roger', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]}, 
                   {'name': 'albert', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [1, 1]}],
        'zebra': [{'name': 'roger', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [0, 0]},
                  {'name': 'albert', 'zone': 'forrest', 'space': [1, 1]}]}

for species in data.values():
    for animal in species:
        if animal['name'] == 'albert':
            animal['space'] = [50, 50]
```

Or with an equivalent generator expression (shorter but not as clear):

```
for albert in (a for s in data.values() for a in s if a['name'] == 'albert'):
    albert['space'] = [50, 50]
```

Result:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
{'donkey': [{'name': 'roger', 'space': [0, 0], 'zone': 'forrest'},
            {'name': 'albert', 'space': [50, 50], 'zone': 'forrest'}],
 'zebra': [{'name': 'roger', 'space': [0, 0], 'zone': 'forrest'},
           {'name': 'albert', 'space': [50, 50], 'zone': 'forrest'}]}
```

Comment: `.viewvalues()` doesn't create a copy unnecesserely as `.values()` does on Python 2.

Comment: i get this error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" but i dont know what it means

Comment: @user1082764 - The example data that you gave is not valid Python code, please add a `print self.object_attr` before you see the error and edit your question with the output.

Comment: @user1082764 - I updated my answer with something that should work better given the format of your data.